# The getter 'documents' was called on null in Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I click on chat tab. It displays red screen error for few seconds. Then it successfully retrieves data. When I click on error. It takes me to second streambuilder.

> I/flutter (17397): The getter 'documents' was called on null.

> I/flutter (17397): Receiver: null

> I/flutter (17397): Tried calling: documents

```
Widget chatRoomsList(){
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: chatRooms,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                return StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("chatRoom").document(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chatRoomId"]).collection("Chats").orderBy("time",descending: true).limit(1).snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot1) {
                      return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot1.data.documents.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                            return  ChatRoomsTile(
                              userName:snapshot.data.documents[index].data['chatRoomId'].toString().replaceAll("_", "").replaceAll(Constants.myName, ""),
                              chatRoomId: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chatRoomId"].toString(),
                              message: snapshot1.data.documents[index1]["message"].toString(),
                              Time:snapshot1.data.documents[index1]["time"],
                            );
                          }):Container();

                    });
              }):Container();
        });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is inside the second `StreamBuilder` you have.

In the builder there, you are checking if the `snapshot` has data:

```
snapshot.hasData
```

You should actually be checking for if `snapshot1` has data:

```
snapshot1.hasData
```

So as the condition returns true always (as `snapshot` has data at that point), but the actual data being used is from `snapshot1`, it shows an error, until it actually gets some data in `snapshot1` from the stream.